# how do i accept object from a form request using laravel and turn it into array

Tags: laravel, reactjs

```
    {
        $student = Student::find($id)->user_works;

        $works = $requests['sample_work']; 

        foreach($student as $id => $student_work)
        {
            $work = UserWork::find($student_work->id);
            $work->update(['sample_work' => $works[$id]]);
            $sample_work[]= $work;
        }

        return response()->json($sample_work, 200);
    }
```

The returned request are objects*[Object, Object, Object]*, and I need them turned into array for updating each **sample_works** of a student.

Comment: Can't you just `json_encode()` the array prior to sending out the response?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not loop all through your $works

```
foreach($works as $work)
{
     // then access it like you access an array
     ....... = $work['id];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Laravel has a toArray method out of the box for converting a collection.

try this

```
{
        $student = Student::find($id)->user_works;

        $works = $requests['sample_work']; 

        foreach($student as $id => $student_work)
        {
            $work = UserWork::find($student_work->id);
            $work->update(['sample_work' => $works[$id]]);
            $sample_work[]= $work->toArray();
        }

        return response()->json($sample_work, 200);
    }
```

Link to the docs: https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/collections#method-toarray